# MacBook autocorrects "The Bible" to "the Bible"

Tags: keyboard, safari, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is have the flexibility to write the following sentences:

> **The Bible** says in John 3:16, "For God so loved the world that He gave
>   His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him should not perish
>   but have everlasting life." (NKJV)

or

> Let's look at what **the Bible** says in John 3:16. "For God so loved the
>   world that He gave His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him
>   should not perish but have everlasting life." (NKJV)

My problem is that my MacBook always autocorrects the string "The Bible" to "the Bible" no matter its location in the sentence. This happens in TextEdit as well as Safari so it's not just a Safari thing. I've checked the Text tab under Keyboard in System Preferences and "the Bible" isn't there. I've also checked ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary and it's blank. I've tried right clicking the selection to bring up the little menu to Add Spelling or Unlearn Spelling but I don't see those options.

Here is a picture of the problem as I'm typing.

[image: Autocorrect when typing]

Here is a picture of my text replacement settings.

[image: Text replacement settings]

Here is a picture of the right click drop down menu.

[image: Right click drop down menu]

Here is a picture of the Show Spelling and Grammar window.

[image: Spelling and Grammar window]

My laptop details:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with a fresh install of High Sierra. I'm currently on macOs High Sierra 10.13.5 (17F77).

Comment: I don't think macOS recognizes the 'the' as needing to be capitalized.  You can should be able to add the string 'The Bible" as a replacement to 'the Bible' in `Keyboard -> Text` as a replacement string.

Comment: That doesn't work. The settings page says "original text can't contain spaces".

Comment: The problem is I need it both ways. I would like to start sentences with "The Bible" and I would like to refer to "the Bible" midway through sentences. I just need it to not give me an autocorrection.

Comment: Yea, I forgot about that.  You can do Replace -> 'theBible' and With -> 'The Bible' or any such similar phrase.  I have many of phrases setup that way on my Mac.

Comment: Does this occur when logged in as another user on your MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

This is (sort of) expected behavior because the name of the book is not *The Bible* but rather *Bible* or *Holy Bible* or *King James Bible*, etc.

When referring to it, you say/write the Holy Bible.

So, this isn't a "spelling" issue where you can add this to a dictionary rather it has to do with grammar.  Unfortunately, it's trying to anticipate what you're typing and erroneously making the correction.  You either have to go back and manually change it back or click the "X" when it pops up so it doesn't make the change.

There's a good [reference on capitalization](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp) rules and it appears what the grammar check is attempting to follow.

Comment: It's not a special case because "bible" can be used as a common noun, e.g. "He wrote the bible on computers." His system also suggests a lowercase "the" when it's the first word in the sentence. There's no autocorrect or spelling either way on my Mac, something got messed up in his dictionary and should clear it.

Comment: I tested it on a "virgin" install of High Sierra (in a VM).  It's that way "out of the box"

Comment: Mine doesn't care how I capitalise it, or not. I can as easily type the bible or The Bible, I get no autocorrect either way. That would lead me to believe [sorry;) that at some point in the past it's been corrected manually & is saved somewhere in the morass that is user-defined spelling suggestions.

Comment: @Tetsujin - it doesn't auto correct in El Cap but does on a virgin HS install.

Comment: i'm on HS, but it's far from 'virgin'... it's slept with a lot of OSes in its time, on a base system that was last freshly-installed in 08... direct line of inheritance ever since. So I can't test without pushing a new OS to a spare drive.

Comment: Allan, Tetsujin, I did do a fresh reinstall of High Sierra. I'll update the question.